# Highlight the current search match in man pages

Tags: search, man, highlighting

When I open a man page, for example `man chmod` and I hit `/` for searching a string in the page I can see all the matching strings highlighted.

Pressing `n` or `N` will focus on the next/previous matching string.

Is there a way to highlight the current match (the one with the focus) differently from all the matching strings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is controlled via `MANPAGER`.

`Manual pages` defaults to the `pager` of `less -is`.

You can just highlight the current selection:

```
man -P "less -isg" <command>
```

Or set the `MANPAGER` variable:

```
export MANPAGER="less -isg"
```

You could also use `vim` where the cursor is highlighted so the current selection will appear differently.:

```
 man -P "sh -c \"col -b | vim -c 'set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nonu' \
    -c 'nnoremap i <nop>' \
    -c 'nnoremap <Space> <C-f>' \
    -c 'noremap q :quit<CR>' -\"" <command>
```

*Taken from [Zameer Manji](http://zameermanji.com/blog/2012/12/30/using-vim-as-manpager/):*

> 1. ft=man enables the coloring of the man page.
> 2. ts=8 ensures the width of tab characters matches less.
> 3. nomod removes the modification warning when trying to quit.
> 4. nonu removes line numbers.
> 5. nolist disables listchars so trailing whitespace and extra tabs are not highlighted.
> 6. nnoremap i  ensures that we do not accidentally enter insert mode when viewing the man page.

*Plus my own option to use space to paginate and `quit` with `q`:*

```
-c 'nnoremap <Space> <C-f>'
-c 'noremap q :quit<CR>'
```

*Set it as your default pager by adding it to your default profile:*

```
export MANPAGER="sh -c \"col -b | vim -c 'set ft=man ts=8 nomod nolist nonu' \
    -c 'nnoremap i <nop>' \
    -c 'nnoremap <Space> <C-f>' \
    -c 'noremap q :quit<CR>' -\""
```

Comment: thanks, "less -isg" will highlight the current match but not all the others. Is there a way to highlight it differently? Also is PAGER a global variable to export at shell startup?

Comment: Yes `export MANPAGER=` can be added to your `shell` profile. I have added another option to use `vim` instead which will give you a different current selection.

Comment: Thanks again, any way to reach the same result using the `less` version?

Comment: There is a way to use [pygments](http://superuser.com/a/337640) to highlight the pages in `less`, although I have not tried combining this with `man`.